# Easily save and read basic game data from files in Java?

Tags: java

What is the easiest (simplest) way to read and write game data to a file? Necessary game data is: gameStage(int), playerName (String), playerHealth (int), playerArmour (int), playerInventory (array of 5 Item objects, each has 2 Strings (itemType, itemName) and 1 or 2 ints (itemCount, itemDamage/itemHealing).

The format I would like (so I can easily use Scanner) is:

```
gameStage
playerName
playerHealth
playerArmour
SLOT1
itemType
itemName
itemCount
itemDamage
END1
SLOT2
... etc
STOP
```

I'm trying to work with Scanner to read from a file and BufferedWriter (which I'm unfamiliar with) to write to the text file. Everything is being stored in one file, and is being overwritten each time the game is saved.

What I am really asking is: Is there a way to do this using only Scanner and BufferedWriter, and if so, how do I do it?

If not, is there a way to do this without having to spend hours learning new things? I'm pressed for time.

I appreciate any help that I get, I've been using Java in school for a bit over a year and I am decently proficient but file saving has never been a focus of mine.

Thanks!

P.S. I'm new to Stack Overflow.

EDIT: Added one more int, gameStage, which is not attached to my Player object.

Comment: I'd use a JSON serialisation library like Jackson or Gson.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use BufferedReader and BufferedWriter. But in this case, I probably use ObjectOutputSream and ObjectInputStram. I think everything you said, they are player's attributes, if I'm correcte, you should use OOS and OIS. Remember to use these classes, "Player" class has to implement Serializable and it has to be imported.

Comment: Could you explain or link an explanation of how to use BufferedReader and BufferedWriter? I'm trying to go as simple as possible.

Comment: Simple class that it reads line by line and write line by line: import java.io.*;
public class TestBuffered{
 public static void main(String args[]){
  BufferedReader in=null;
  BufferedWriter out=null;
  String aux="";
  try{
   in=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
   out=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file2.txt"));
   while((aux=in.readLine())!=null){
    out.write(aux);
    out.flush();
    out.newLine();
   }
   if(out!=null) out.close(); if(in!=null) in.close();
  }catch(IOException e){}
 }
}

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I was looking for, my game is going great!